AWS Cloudfront - headers not thrown from code
I have a static site (Nuxt/Nitro) which has some headers responses (CSP, XSS etc...).
I deployed first on Netlify, I got my custom headers thrown by the code.
I had to change hosting and deploy on AWS Cloudfront (for features reason).
I noticed that no headers from my code is thrown.It seems to be overriden by default AWS headers that you can't delete.
Should I deport my header on AWS Console OR is it possible just to authorize headers from my code ?
